# Chaining multiple methods fluently akin to a Stream without the verbosity of the Optional type

Tags: java, functional-programming, monads, option-type

In a Spring application I tend to take the request body in a controller method and want to pipe it fluently through multiple method calls (returning different types along the way) such as in the following (simplified) example:

```
public ResponseEntity<FooDto> postFoo(@RequestBody final FooDto requestBody) {
  return Optional.of(requestBody) // Optional<FooDto>
      .map(mapper::fromDto) // Optional<FooEntity>
      .map(service::insertEntity) // Optional<FooEntity>
      .map(mapper::fromEntity) // Optional<FooDto>
      .map(dto -> ResponseEntity.created(/* ... */).body(dto).build()) // Optional<ResponseEntity<FooDto>>
      .orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
}
```

As you can see I am tempted to apply some FP patterns but the Optional class isn't really suited to do so since the "optionality" implied is artificial and the underlying object of interest should never be empty in the first place. Therefore the final exception won't (hopefully) ever be thrown and alternatively just calling `Optional::get` isn't really a great option either since Sonarlint complains about an unchecked get call and rightfully so.

Is there any idiomatic way available, maybe even in conjunction with vavr or other FP libraries, to express such a chain of methods better than with such artifical Optional constructs? Otherwise I might have to refrain from doing so and revert back to a classic imperative approach with a dozen of variables.

EDIT: The way I attempt to use Optional easily gets out of hand if working with methods that return `Either<ErrorReason, Optional<FooEntity>>` which makes this an `Optional<Either<ErrorReason, Optional<FooEntity>>>` ending up not legible anymore.

Comment: What's not clear in your question though is the signature of `fromDto`, `insertEntity` and `fromEntity` and why would you return request body type in response?

Comment: @Naman I have added some type hints similar to IntelliJ, hope that helps.

Comment: If your question is `orElseThrow` never going to execute, then what if  `RequestBody` is null ? @ChristianIvicevic

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why you don't like your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest way to perform what you're looking for is to restore to the imperative style such as:

```
public ResponseEntity<FooDto> postFoo(final FooDto requestBody) {
    final FooEntity fooEntity = fromDto(requestBody);
    final FooEntity updatedEntity = insertEntity(fooEntity); // should be void?
    final FooDto responseDto = fromEntity(updatedEntity);
    return ResponseEntity.created(/* ... */)
            .body(responseDto)
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Naman that an imperative style is probably the cleanest way in this case.

If you really really want to do some `Optional` style like flow you can create your own class

```java
public final class Value<T> {
  private final T value;

  // Private constructor to force usage of static construction
  private Value(T value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  // Static constructor Optional style
  public static <T> Value<T> of(T value) {
    return new Value<>(value);
  }

  public <R> Value<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper) {
    return new Value<>(mapper.apply(this.value));
  }

  // method to unwrap value
  public T get() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Then you would use it like

```java
public ResponseEntity<FooDto> postFoo(@RequestBody final FooDto requestBody) {
  return Value.of(requestBody) // Value<FooDto>
      .map(mapper::fromDto) // Value<FooEntity>
      .map(service::insertEntity) // Value<FooEntity>
      .map(mapper::fromEntity) // Value<FooDto>
      .map(dto -> ResponseEntity.created(/* ... */).body(dto).build()) // Value<ResponseEntity<FooDto>>
      .get();
}
```

Again, I highly discourage this solution and I would just opt for using imperative style.